# HeidiSQL Convert varchar into a Datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, varchar, heidisql

I've inherited a database that has `varchars` instead of `datetimes` and I want to be able to do some reporting that says if one date is less than another.

I have this database query:

```
Select 
    RENEWDATE, 
    (CONCAT(substring(renewdate, 1,4), "-", substring(renewdate, 5,2), "-", substring(renewdate, 7,2), " 23:59:59")) 
FROM solutionsdmp 
WHERE  Approval = "Approved" 
GROUP BY Author 
ORDER BY  Author ASC
```

Which converts this date format: `20160217` into this: `2016-02-17 23:59:59`

I have two dates a last modififed and a renew date. They're both stored as `varchars` but in different formats. One is stored as a `varchar` but formatted like a `datetime` `2015-02-17 23:59:59` and then the other as listed above is shown as `20160217`. I want to be able to convert them both to datetimes so that I can run a query and check whether one is less than the other. So that I can see whether or not the renewal date has passed.

I've tried a lot of variations that aren't working, but this is my latest attempt:

```
    SELECT 
        RENEWDATE, 
        CONVERT(DATETIME,(CONCAT(substring(renewdate, 1,4), "-", substring(renewdate, 5,2), "-", substring(renewdate, 7,2), " 23:59:59"))) 
    FROM solutionsdmp 
    WHERE  Approval = "Approved" 
    GROUP BY Author 
    ORDER BY  Author ASC
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: *I want to be able to say if this date is less than this date*....can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @Hackerman I've updated the post :)

Comment: You can use an if in the query, to check the one that has the greater or lesser value...https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/if-function/ ...also for the conversion you can use https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/functions/str_to_date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to come up with a workaround solution on my own, thought I'd post it here for anyone else who needs the help!

I did a `CAST`and then used `HAVING`to do my filtering on. It worked for me!

```
Select 
     Author, 
     Problem,
     CAST(Last_Modified_DATE AS DATETIME) AS lmd, 
     CAST((CONCAT(substring(renewdate, 1,4), "-", substring(renewdate, 5,2), "-", substring(renewdate, 7,2), " 23:59:59")) AS DATETIME) AS rend
from solutionsdmp
WHERE Approval = "Approved"
HAVING 
lmd < rend
order by 
Author ASC
```